# How do you exclude chat when applying label via filter in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I want to create a filter in Gmail that has the rule 
`to:me -cc:me` but I only want it to apply to emails, not Hangouts chat messages.

When I try to include `-in:chats` in my filter Gmail warns me that this will not work...

> Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g.
>   "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are
>   not recommended as they will never match incoming mail. Do you still
>   wish to continue to the next step?

Is there some other filter criteria that I can use which identifies the message type as email only?

Comment: https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/09/gmails-option-for-excluding-chats-from.html?m=1

Comment: Oh, that's just goofy.  If you put `-in:chats` in the field "has the words" you'll get the warning.  But if you have it in the main portion of the filter or if you check that box "Don't include chats" it works.  Thank you @ytpillai

Comment: You got it, converted comment to answer so others can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [this url](https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/09/gmails-option-for-excluding-chats-from.html?m=1). Basically, if you use the advanced filter option, you can check the box that says "Don't include chats".